# Issue with Android Emulator DPI

Tags: android

I am having an issue with my Android Emulator looking strange on my monitor. The emulator works just fine and is fairly fast (thank you, Intel HAXM), but I have an issue with the emulator screen looking strange.

[image: Android Emulator DPI Issue]

Here's the configuration for the emulator.

[image: Android Emulator Configuration]

[image: Android Emulator Configuration]

What's the problem with my emulator? I have the emulator size scaled down here so that it fits into my monitor dimensions, but I did launch it once without scaling it down, and the effect was exactly the same as it is here.

Comment: Do you have different DPI settings on your Windows? You could try and disable the DPI scaling on the emulator (through Windows via the 'compatibility' settings)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by scaling the window size of the emulator up a bit. By doing this, I was able to utilize more of my screen, and the image quality was improved. Emulator performance was further improved by setting the emulator to use my GPU and reducing the ram the emulator can allocate to itself.